# permission update for a file in google drive

Tags: python, google-api, google-drive-api

I want to upload a file into the google drive in a particular folder and to give access to the file only to some specific email addresses.

Uploading is already done. Now I want to update the permissions of the file.

(using python)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you follow the [Python quick start](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/python)  Once that you have that working and you are logged in with the user who has permissions for the file.  You can then go about creating new permissions for the other users using

You might want to start with a permisisons.list to see whats already there.

```
perms = service.permissions().list(fileId=PARENT_ID).execute()

print ("PERMISSIONS:")
for perm in perms["items"]:
    for p in perm:
        print (p, perm[p])
```

Then run a [Permissions create](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/permissions/create) on the users who are not.